# JavaScript undo onclick action?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have an HTML checkbox. It uses an onclick javascript event to increment an integer var by 1.

I want to decrement the var by one if the checkbox is then unchecked. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.checkbox').click (function(){
  var thisCheck = $(this);

  if ( thischeck.is(':checked') ) {
    // Do increment
  }
  else { // DO decrement }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just use a conditional statement to check whether the checkbox has been unchecked inside the function where you check whether the function has been checked and increment the value.

```
$("#inputid input:checkbox").change(function() {
                    var ischecked= $(this).is(':checked');
                    if(!ischecked)
                      var val = val-1;
                });
```